# How to include a DocLink in a MIME Email in Lotus Notes?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

I wish to obtain the `DocLink` or the value of the link about the document to include in a `MIME` email using `LotusScript`, but I don't know how to do it.

I have this:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)

    Dim s As New NotesSession 
    Dim db As NotesDatabase 
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim body As NotesMIMEEntity 
    Dim header As NotesMIMEHeader 
    Dim stream As NotesStream

    Set db = s.CurrentDatabase 
    Set stream = s.CreateStream 
    s.ConvertMIME = False

    Set doc = db.CreateDocument 
    doc.Form = "Memo"

    Set body = doc.CreateMIMEEntity 
    Set header = body.CreateHeader("Subject")

    Call header.SetHeaderVal("HTML message") 
    Set header = body.CreateHeader("To")
    Call header.SetHeaderVal("email_domain")

    Call stream.writetext(|<HTML>|) 
    Call stream.writetext(|<body>|) 
    user$ = s.CommonUserName 
    Call stream.writetext(|<br><font size="+5" color="red">| & user$ &|</font>|) 
    Call stream.WriteText(|<br><a href="notes:///server/etc/etc">Notes</a><br>|)    
    Call stream.writetext(|</body>|) 
    Call stream.writetext(|</html>|)

    Call body.SetContentFromText(stream, "text/HTML;charset=UTF-8", ENC_IDENTITY_7BIT) 
    Call doc.Send(False) 
    s.ConvertMIME = True 

End Sub
```

In this code I can include the `<a></a>` tags with an URL Notes, but I really want to generate the link of this document like using the `AppendDocLink`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution with `UniversalID`. I retrieve this `ID` of the document and I add to the URL, like this.

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)

    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim s As New NotesSession 
    Dim db As NotesDatabase 
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim doc2 As NotesDocument
    Dim body As NotesMIMEEntity 
    Dim header As NotesMIMEHeader 
    Dim stream As NotesStream
    Dim urldoc As String

    Set doc2 = ws.CurrentDocument.Document

    Set db = s.CurrentDatabase 
    Set stream = s.CreateStream 
    s.ConvertMIME = False

    urldoc = doc2.UniversalID

    Set doc = db.CreateDocument 
    doc.Form = "Memo"

    Set body = doc.CreateMIMEEntity 
    Set header = body.CreateHeader("Subject")

    Call header.SetHeaderVal("HTML message") 
    Set header = body.CreateHeader("To")
    Call header.SetHeaderVal("email")

    Call stream.writetext(|<HTML>|) 
    Call stream.writetext(|<body>|) 
    user$ = s.CommonUserName 
    Call stream.writetext(|<br><font size="+5" color="red">| & user$ &|</font>|) 
    Call stream.WriteText(|<br><a href="Notes://Server/Replica/View/| & urldoc & |">Notes</a><br>|)
    Call stream.writetext(|</body>|) 
    Call stream.writetext(|</html>|)

    Call body.SetContentFromText(stream, "text/HTML;charset=UTF-8", ENC_IDENTITY_7BIT) 
    Call doc.Send(False) 
    s.ConvertMIME = True 

End Sub
```